# return statement not passing value

Tags: python, recursion, return

Total newbie here......The return statement in the following code is not passing the value calculated by the function. Does anyone has any ideas ?

````
def pagos(B,P,r,c):
    UB = (B-P)*(1+(r/12)) 

    if (c==12):
        print(UB) #This is to establish if UB is actually reaching return statement#
        return UB
    c +=1
    pagos(UB,P,r,c)

P=200
B=10000
r=0.2
c=0

R = pagos(B,P,r,c)

print("Answer :"+str(R))```

9472.628606761953                                                                                                                                                                  
Answer :None
````

Comment: As it si shown in the last two lines UB gets printed but return is passing the value 'None"

Comment: Because in your defined function, it returns nothing. Put `return` to return the resulted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `return` in the recursive call:

```
def pagos(B,P,r,c):
    UB = (B-P)*(1+(r/12)) 

    if (c==12):
        print(UB)
        return UB
    c +=1
    return pagos(UB,P,r,c)
```

Comment: is correct, this is a common mistake getting people new to programming: `return` doesn't exit the entire stack of calls, it just returns to wherever it was called from and continues execution from there. By returning the result from the nested call, a whole bunch of returns can 'bubble' the answer all the way back to the start.

Answer (score -1):

You should `return pagos(UB,P,r,c)` for the recursive procedure.